# Android GPS not Showing or writing to file

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an app that monitors the accelerometer and the GPS and out puts them to a file.

I have defaulted the GPS to 0,0. But it doesn't seem to change.

```
public String location = "0 , 0";

    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
        arg0.getLatitude();
    arg0.getLongitude();
    location = arg0.getLongitude() + "," + arg0.getLatitude();

    locationText = TextView.class.cast(location);
    }
```

The text view is there to show if it is acutaully changing, but that doesn't seem to update either.

[image: screenshot of app]

The location text view is at the top of the screen.

Im not sure what else I can  include to help you help me. But if there is anything let me know.

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
```

This is the code of the accelerometer, which works, and the GPS which doesn't.

[image: Java code]

Thanking you and a happy new year.

**CODE**

```
public class AccelOrientExample extends Activity implements SensorEventListener, LocationListener {


// Accelerometer X, Y, and Z values
private TextView accelXValue;
private TextView accelYValue;
private TextView accelZValue;

// Orientation X, Y, and Z values
private TextView orientXValue;
private TextView orientYValue;
private TextView orientZValue;


private TextView locationText;
private TextView toWrite;

public Toast myToast;
public String accel;
public int counter = 0;
public String orientData;

private LocationManager lm;
private Toast loc;
public String location = "0 , 0";

private SensorManager sensorManager = null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get a reference to a SensorManager
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Capture accelerometer related view elements
    accelXValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.accel_x_value);
    accelYValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.accel_y_value);
    accelZValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.accel_z_value);

    // Capture orientation related view elements
    orientXValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.orient_x_value);
    orientYValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.orient_y_value);
    orientZValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.orient_z_value);

    // Initialize accelerometer related view elements
    accelXValue.setText("0.00");
    accelYValue.setText("0.00");
    accelZValue.setText("0.00");

    // Initialize orientation related view elements
    orientXValue.setText("0.00");
    orientYValue.setText("0.00");
    orientZValue.setText("0.00");

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

}

/**/

// This method will update the UI on new sensor events
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    synchronized (this) { 
        while(counter < 15)
        {
            if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION)
            {
                orientXValue.setText(Float.toString(sensorEvent.values[0]));
                orientYValue.setText(Float.toString(sensorEvent.values[1]));
                orientZValue.setText(Float.toString(sensorEvent.values[2]));
            }
            MyFile file = new MyFile();
            file.createFile("OrientData.txt");

            orientData = sensorEvent.values[0] + "," + sensorEvent.values[1] + "," + sensorEvent.values[2] + "\n";

            file.write(orientData);
            counter ++;
        }
        if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        {
            accelXValue.setText(Float.toString(sensorEvent.values[0]));
            accelYValue.setText(Float.toString(sensorEvent.values[1]));
            accelZValue.setText(Float.toString(sensorEvent.values[2]));

            accel = sensorEvent.values[0] + "," + sensorEvent.values[1] + "," + sensorEvent.values[2] + ",";
        }


    }
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
    synchronized (this) {
    lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    arg0.getLatitude();
    arg0.getLongitude();
    location = arg0.getLongitude() + "," + arg0.getLatitude();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Test",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

            public void run() {
                locationText.setText(location);
            }

        });
    }
}

    public void FileLogger(String accel, String location)
    {
        MyFile file = new MyFile();
        file.createFile("RoadData.txt");

        String toWrite = accel + location + "\n";
        file.write(toWrite);
    }

public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    Log.e("GPS", "provider disabled " + arg0);
}

public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    Log.e("GPS", "provider enabled " + arg0);
}

public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    Log.e("GPS", "status changed to " + arg0 + " [" + arg1 + "]");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Register this class as a listener for the accelerometer sensor
    sensorManager.registerListener(this,
            sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    // ...and the orientation sensor
    sensorManager.registerListener(this,
            sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}



@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // Unregister the listener
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    super.onStop();
}
```

}

Comment: Add the code where you call requestLocationUpdates. It can take 20-30 seconds for the GPS to start sending data, especially if you are indoors. So wait and test outside.

Comment: added the code there, and I'll go outside now

Comment: try adding a toast or dialog message in the code to see method get triggered or not.

Comment: @yoah Going outside didn't work, unless the satilites are down :P waited out for 5 mins and nothing.

Comment: Do you have permissions
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

Comment: @yoah I had them both, but got rid of coarse to see if that would make any difference, it didn't

Comment: @ELSheepO From the screenshot, I see that there is no GPS icon in the notification bar, which indicates that the GPS is not working. Make sure that:
(1) Your code to requestLocationUpdates gets called. Put a Toast or log there
(2) Go to Settingsd/Location and make sure Use GPS is enabled

Comment: The satillite in the top left corner is the GPS icon. The method is never reached by the looks of things, because it isn't even creating the file to write the data to.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try below

```
locationText.setText(location);
```

instead of

```
locationText = TextView.class.cast(location);
```

i expect locationText to be a TextView and

you requested location updates correctly and

added permission in manifest correctly and

the location update code is not getting executed by non-ui thread.

Comment: the setText doesn't show up anything either. I should show the 0,0 before the GPS has been started, but it shows up empty. I'm going to throw in a toast to check it now.

Comment: The toast never comes up, the code is in the question. It's highlighted at the bottom.

Comment: Type Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Test",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: The test toast never shows. I put it into the onLocationChanged method. Is the method in the right place?

Answer (score 1):

You might have the location services off, check that the provider is first available with;

```
locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
```

Like @Javantor said you need to make sure that the manifest includes;

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

and you are updating on the UI Thread. Try putting this in the onLocationUpdated code;

```
       runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                locationText.setText(location);
            }

        });
```

While it shouldn't make a difference, requesting the LocationManager this way;

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

with the time set to 0 instead of 1000ms ensures you get the updates as fast as they can come in.

Can you add some logging to the onLocationChanged method? That will let you know if the GPS data is being received at all.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be recieved at all. I have a logger and its just writing the default 0,0 that I set it to higher up in the code. The run on ui thread hasn't done anything. I have all the permissions set and the phone settings allow apps to use GPS.

Comment: Maybe its something simple within your activity. Can you post your full activity code, or at least the lifecycle calls (onCreate/onStart/onStop, etc.) calls?

Comment: Its going to be long but I'll post it. :P

Comment: Just tried it out on a GNex and it seems to be working now. Make sure you set the locationText view, ` locationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gps_value);` and you can remove the synchronized calls.

Comment: Bizarrely enough, I can't seem to get it working on a Nexus 4. The GPS doesn't seem to lock on. [link]https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2[link] is showing the gps not working

Comment: Thats my problem too, the GPS just doesn't stick. It just keeps searching for it. Did it create the two files, orientdata.txt and roaddata.txt for you?

Comment: I just managed to get it working finally. I shut off wifi and mobile data and allowed it to get a lock and then turned them back on. Likely its a AGPS configuration with the carrier that isn't working properly. Also, I edited out the file creation scripts for testing but that code looks like it will work

Comment: Did you change any of the code or was it just turning on and off the wifi AND (?) the mobile data? So its my network/phone thats the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try launching Google Maps first and let it pinpoint your current location. Sometimes Location returns null because recent location list has been cleared. Also try this method to iterate over the currently enabled providers, not just the best one. This gives you a slightly higher chance or getting some coordinates returned. Hope this helps man. Good luck

```
private Location getLastKnownLocation() {
List<String> providers = mLocationManager.getProviders(true);
Location bestLocation = null;
for (String provider : providers) {
    Location l = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    ALog.d("last known location, provider: %s, location: %s", provider,
            l);

    if (l == null) {
        continue;
    }
    if (bestLocation == null
            || l.getAccuracy() < bestLocation.getAccuracy()) {
        ALog.d("found best last known location: %s", l);
        bestLocation = l;
    }
}
if (bestLocation == null) {
    return null;
}
return bestLocation;
```

}

Comment: But it shouldn't return null, shouldn't it return the (0,0) I had it defaulted to? Using maps it has my current location, but its constantly searching for GPS, which confuses me because how would it know where I am :/.

Comment: it never makes the log of the providers or finds the gps